# Do tag wiki excerpt edits count to the Research Assistant badge?

Tags: support, badges, tag-wiki

The [image: Research Assistant] badge states that one must make 50 tag wiki edits.  Does this include editing tag wiki excerpts?

(I've been doing a few tag wiki edits, but so far it has only registered 3 of them; most of them were focused on fixing the excerpts and they may not have counted because of that)

Comment: No, tag wiki excerpts do not count.

Comment: ^--- As explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121517/research-assistant-badge-requirements)

Comment: Also, [you aren't the first one to be confused by this.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177047)

Comment: To the extent people look at tags at all, I bet the excerpts are read more often than the wikis, because the excerpts are shown by default and, well, are just _shorter_.  It's odd we consider them less important badge-wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, wiki excerpts don't count, only the main body.

From the badge's [deploy announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121484/162511):

> I wanted to add a push to wiki editing, not excerpt editing (which is forced anyway). So... the badge counts distinct tag wikis you edit excluding excerpts.