# Research Assistant badge progress incorrect?

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

In my profile, it says I have 8/50 tag wiki edits towards the badge. In [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/77365/progress-towards-research-assistant-badge), it says I have 16.

Yesterday, I had 8 tag wiki edits, made 3 more, but I don't see them added up to 11 total yet.

What could the issue be?

Comment: Blame caching..

Comment: If it is caching, what can I do to clear it?

Comment: Like it might be server-side caching that you can't do anything about. Just wait it out and it will update by tomorrow.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For once in our lives it's not (completely) caching's fault.

```sql
select
    COUNT(DISTINCT Posts.Id) as TagWikisEdited,
    CAST(CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2),
         COUNT(DISTINCT Posts.Id) * 2.0)  as VARCHAR(6)) + '%' as Progress
from SuggestedEdits as Edit
LEFT JOIN Posts on Edit.PostId=Posts.Id
WHERE Edit.OwnerUserId=##UserID:int##
AND Posts.PostTypeId in (4,5)
AND Edit.ApprovalDate is not null
```

The [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/77365/progress-towards-research-assistant-badge) you used counts suggested edits on tag wiki excerpts, but [only edits on tag wiki bodies](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273156/880772) are considered for Research Assistant.

There's a more accurate query that [counts tag wiki edits by the tag names](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/211740/progress-towards-research-assistant-badge-by-tag-wiki-titles). Note that it uses the suggested edits table, so won't be accurate for 20k users who can edit directly.

Comment: Great, this more accurate query does have 11. Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that the Data Explorer doesn't contain edits for deleted posts, so it might show a much smaller number of edits than were actually made. For me the discrepancy is 11 to 25. It's also kind of strange than one of those tags is blank for me.

Comment: @pnuts That must be it. Both of you are above 20k and can directly edit tags, but the second query I mentioned only use the suggested edit table. Try this: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/407869/tag-wiki-edit-count